# No Data Available When Query on Apache Jena Fuseki

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm new with Apache Jena Fuseki and SparQL. I have a problem when I tried to query data on Fuseki. The data I used is from DBpedia named 'Topical Concepts' (can be found [here](https://wiki.dbpedia.org/downloads-2016-10)). I upload the data through the control panel on a browser (through the default port 3030) and used the query below:

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?subject
}
LIMIT 25
```

I got a null table and a message "no data available in this table". However, when I installed Fuseki and do the same thing on my Mac (the problem in above happened on my desktop with Ubuntu 16 operation system), I successfully got 25 entries of the data. I don't think it is the problem of the operation system, but I really have no idea about why it happened. Does anybody encounter the same problem?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "SparQL"; it's "[SPARQL](http://dbpedia.org/page/SPARQL)"

Comment: My mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SPARQL query, you have the following pattern:

```
?subject ?predicate ?subject
```

Notice that you repeat `?subject`. This query effectively asks: "give me all RDF triples for which the subject is the same value as the object". It's likely that the reason you're not getting a result is simply that no such triples exist in your database.

As for why this didn't happen on a Mac, without more info about your setup we can only speculate. It's possible that you configured your database slightly differently there (e.g. enabling a reasoner which would result in additional RDF triples that *do* match the query), or it might be as simple as you did a slightly different query there.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. I did not notice that what I queried is "?object ?predicate ?subject". After I changed the query, I got the result. On my Mac, I did change the configuration for querying another dataset before. I haven't figure out what that modification means, but it probably enables the reasoner as you mentioned. Thank you so much for your answer! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am making two assumptions for answering your question:

1. you have two different instances of Jena installed. One on your laptop and one on your desktop.
2. You are sure you have uploaded data, possibly into a named graph and the default is empty

Fuseki, I haven't tried this on TBD, has one feature that, often, by default is set to query only the default graph. If in the config setting you activate `tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ;` then it will query all the graphs. Before changing the settings, please do check that this is true. You could check by executing this query:

```
SELECT distinct ?g
WHERE {
   graph ?g{
       ?s ?p ?o 
    }
 }
```

If you get a result, that means you need to change the settings for it to work, or be mindful of this fact and always call your queries with graphs (as in the above query).

For more explanation please refer to https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very useful. But my problem is because of the mistake of my query. I should have double checked it before asking.